# grep -v -f of empty file different between script and command line on OS X

Tags: bash, macos, bsd

In bash, in Terminal on my Mac, (but not in Linux), grep -v -f behaves differently depending on whether it's executed at the command line or in a script. From the command line:

```
$ touch empty-file  #create an empty file
$ printf 'foo' | grep -v -f empty-file
foo
```

That's as expected. But when that line is in a script, it outputs nothing. Here's the script:

```
$ cat grep-v-in-script.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf 'foo\n' | grep -v -f empty-file
printf 'end of script\n'
```

When I execute that script:

```
$ ./grep-v-in-script.sh 
end of script
```

If I run that same script in Linux it works as expected:

```
herdrick@some-linux-server:~$ ./grep-v-in-script.sh 
foo
end of script
```

FWIW on my Mac if I change the 'grep -v -f' to 'grep -f', then it again outputs nothing, but this time that is expected.

Here's my bash version:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Are you sure that `empty-file` in your second example is in fact empty? The behavior you're showing makes me wonder if it contains a newline. How did you produce it? What does `ls -l` report its size as?

Comment: `printf 'foo' | grep -v -f empty-file` produces no output using BSD `grep` 2.5.1; what version(s) of `grep` are you using? (This doesn't really have anything to do with `bash`.)

Comment: I can't reproduce the Terminal output you showed. I'm using High Sierra.

Comment: I can reproduce it on Mojave with "grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD". I see that GNU `grep -f <(:)` exits immediately with failure, while GNU `grep -f <(:) -v` waits and matches all. Meanwhile, macOS `grep` exits immediately with failure in both cases. POSIX says that `-f` will "Read one or more patterns from the file", and does not address the issue of zero lines

Comment: @cody in all cases I used `touch empty-file` to create that file. `ls -al empty-file`  shows it has 0 bytes.

Comment: @chepner when I add `which grep` to the script, it get `/usr/bin/grep`. I get the same from the command line.

Comment: Ah... I had an alias on grep, to use GNU grep. My mistake. Indeed there is no difference between doing this at the command line and in a script. The issue is, as @that-other-guy points out, a matter of BSD grep vs GNU grep.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simply an incompatibility between GNU grep and BSD grep. See the comment on the post by @that-other-guy.

My confusion was due to my having an alias set to use GNU grep. There is, otherwise, no difference between doing this at the command line and in a script.